# java.net.SocketException: error setting options when setting up multicast on Windows

Tags: java, networking, multicast

I get the following exception whem I'm joining a multicast group using Java

```
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:178) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
at java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(MulticastSocket.java:323) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
```

This feature worked earlier but suddenly stopped working

**My code**

- Variables

```
private String address = null;

/** group */
private InetAddress group = null;
    
/** port to broadcast over */
private int port = -1;

/** connected multicast socket */
MulticastSocket socket = null;
```

- Attempting to join

```
group = InetAddress.getByName(address);
socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
socket.joinGroup(group);
```

- Values

  port = 4580

  address = 224.0.0.1

**Specs**

- -OS - Windows 10 Home
- -OS version - 10.0.19044 Build 19044
- -Ram - 40GB (32GB + 8GB)
- -Processor - i7-10510U
- -Java version - 1.8.0_211
- -IDE - Eclipse
- -IDE Version - 2021-03 (4.19.0)
- -IDE Build id - 20210312-0638
- -Tomcat version - 9.0

I have tried following things to resolve the issue

- Added `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to JVM
- Added `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");` to my code
- Disconnecting my laptop from the internet

**Other information**
I have VM wear and wireshark installed (not sure if they affect the behaviour). This exact code worked fine for months even with those programs

Comment: Rather than code snippets, please show a [mcve].  Also, the stack trace you show is incomplete.  Please show the *entire* error message.

Comment: What @dbush said and do you really want to join the group `224.0.0.1`, which is [reserved](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml#multicast-addresses-1)? Even though your port might not clash with other traffic. Moreover, which network interface are you trying to bind to? Your problem might be related to the program binding to an interface not eligible for multicast. In any case, more information is needed.